# Android ViewPagerIndicator - UnderlinePageIndicator on top instead of bottom?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

I'm using ActionBarSherlock + HoloEverywhere + ViewPagerIndicator libraries.

1. Is there a way to place the UnderlinePageIndicator on top instead of bottom?
2. On Jelly Bean, the UnderlinePageIndicator doesn't auto-hide at a few stops, while it works perfectly on GingerBread. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TabPageIndicator and change the look of underline by editing nine-patch PNGs named vpi_*tab*???_holo. There are 6 of them for each screen density.

Answer (score 0):

just set the height as you want:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/pageIndicator"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_pages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```